# What is the name for the subring of the Grothendieck ring of a bialgebra spanned by one-dimensional representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, terminology

Let $B$ be a finite dimensional bialgebra over a field $\Bbbk$.  Let $\mathcal G_0(B)$ be the ring whose underlying additive group is generated by isomorphism classes $[V]$ of finite dimensional $B$-modules $V$ subject to the relations $[B]=[A]+[C]$ if there is an exact sequence $0\rightarrow A\rightarrow B\rightarrow C\rightarrow 0$.  The product is given by $[V][W]=[V\otimes W]$.

Since the tensor product of one-dimensional modules is again one-dimensional, it follows that the additive subgroup generated by one-dimensional modules is a subring.  Does this ring have a standard name and notation?

Comment: Pardon me if I am wrong, but I thought the multiplication in the Grothendieck ring involved induction, and that the product of two 1-dimensionals does not have to be 1-dimensional.

Comment: I think you are thinking of the case where you have a tower of algebras like symmetric group algebras and you first tensor and then induce to get a product on the direct sum of Grothendieck groups.  Here I have no subalgebra to induce from.

Comment: Ah you are right. Thanks for clearing that up.